# Pass state from unrelated components using redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Here I have my top level component `App` that renders my `Header` component and my `FrontPage` component. I also have `react-redux` wired up to check if user is logged in.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import * as actions from "../actions";

//Header Container
import Header from "../Containers/Header";

//Front Page Container
import FrontPage from "../Containers/FrontPage";

class App extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchUser();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <BrowserRouter>
          <div>
            <Header />
            <Route path="/" exact component={FrontPage} />
          </div>
        </BrowserRouter>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default connect(null, actions)(App);
```

In my Header component I have a `ShoppingCart` component that displays the number of items the user has in their cart.

```
class ShoppingCart extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { itemAmount: "0" };
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    const item = await axios.post("/api/items-in-cart-amount");

    if (item.data) {
      this.setState({ itemAmount: item.data.amount });
    }
  }

  //...
}
```

Like so:

[image]

In my `FrontPage` component I have an `AddToCartBtn`, and when it's clicked will update the User's cart in MongoDB

The flow of events goes like this:

1. The user clicks `AddToCartBtn` on product
2. `AddToCartBtn` makes POST request to update User document in MongoDB (adding the productID to their "cart")
3. `ShoppingCart` *SHOULD* re-render and display the new number

**My Problem:** The amount displayed only updates, when I refresh the page. I want to to re-render right after step 2.

I'm aware `ShoppingCart` is not getting re-rendered because its state is not changing.

**Question:** How would I achieve step 3. by using redux or any other method? I'm new to redux so if you can show me implementation of it, that'd be great.

Note: Assume that `ShoppingCart` is several layers down from the `Header` component, and assume `AddToCartBtn` is several layers down from the `FrontPage` component. So passing state/data up from the child (several layers up), and then back down as props to another component isn't very appealing.

Comment: Well at the moment your shopping cart component only gets the number of items in the cart when it's mounted. So when you first mount it (like opening or refreshing the page) it will get the right amount. But where's the logic to update the store with the new number of items when someone adds a product, and where is the logic that connects the shopping cart to this store value?

Comment: That's my question, how would I implement that using redux? Essentially I would want to send a piece of state to my redux store after `AddToCartBtn` finishes the post request, and then `ShoppingCart` would receive props.

Comment: Do you have a backend? Or are you just interfacing your front end directly to your database?

Comment: Yes I have a NodeJS backend, and `AddToCartBtn` makes a post request to my NodeJS route to update the mongodb user cart

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok well I'm going to assume you know the basics about reducers, actions, and connecting components to the store. Let's also assuming you're storing the user's cart info in the store.

Essentially you'd have something like an `UPDATE_USER_CART` action. When a product is clicked, it won't post to the backend itself, it will call this action. In your reducer which implements this action you'd post to your backend Node route, e.g. `/updateusercart`. Now I haven't used MongoDB before so I'm not too sure the specifics of how you'd implement this, but essentially in this route you'd need to do 2 things:

1. Update the user's cart in the DB
2. Get the user's new cart values

If you can do this using only 1 DB query that'd be good, though you may need 2. Then when you have this information you return it in the route's response. The reducer would then update the user's cart information in the store with the new values returned from your backend. That's the basic flow for updating the user cart information in your store.

The second part is connecting your shopping cart to the store, so in your `mapStateToProps` function you'd add the number of cart items in the store. Now that the count is mapped to the store, when you update the store with the new user cart info, the cart icon will get passed the new item count as a prop and get updated.

So in essence: store the user cart info in the Redux state and connect your shopping cart component to it (specifically, the number of items). When an item is clicked, call an action whose reducer posts to the backend route. This route updates user info and returns new cart data. Reducer then overwrites current state data with this new data, triggering an update of connected components (i.e. shopping cart icon).

Comment: Great explanation, I will try try to implement that